React native expo-router protected routes issue
Iam having issues with authentication even tho iam login with firebase and redirected to home page but if i press back button then it go back to signin screen, i have tried adding redirect on tabs auth layout but didnt work
My Rootlayout code :
import React from "react";
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { GluestackUIProvider } from "@gluestack-ui/themed";
import { config } from "@gluestack-ui/config";

import { Slot, Stack } from "expo-router";
import { ActivityIndicator, View } from "react-native";

import { AuthProvider, useAuth } from "@/context/AuthProvider";
import Toast from "react-native-toast-message";
import PartnerForm from "@/components/partnerForm";

export default function RootLayout() {
  return (
    <GluestackUIProvider config={config}>
      <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <AuthProvider>
          <AuthLoader />
        </AuthProvider>
        <Toast />
      </GestureHandlerRootView>
    </GluestackUIProvider>
  );
}

const AuthLoader = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();

  if (isAuthenticated === null) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Stack>
      <Stack.Screen name="(auth)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="expandedMap/[query]"
        options={{ headerShown: true, headerTitle: "Jobs around you" }}
      />
    </Stack>
  );
};


My AuhtProvider code :
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "expo-router";
import { getItem } from "@/store/storage";
import * as Location from "expo-location";
import axios from "axios";

const AuthContext = createContext({
  isAuthenticated: null,
  userLocation: null,
  getUserLocation: () => {},
});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(null);
  const [userLocation, setUserLocation] = useState(null);
  const router = useRouter();

  const getUserLocation = async () => {
    let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== "granted") {
      console.log("Permission to access location was denied");
      return;
    }

    let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
    console.log("LOCATION", location);

    const stateName = await getStateName(location.coords);

    setUserLocation({ ...location.coords, stateName });
  };

  const getStateName = async (coords) => {
    const { latitude, longitude } = coords;
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${latitude},${longitude}&key=${process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY}`
      );
      const data = response.data;

      if (data.status === "OK") {
        const addressComponents = data.results[0].address_components;
        for (let component of addressComponents) {
          if (component.types.includes("administrative_area_level_1")) {
            return component.long_name;
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error with reverse geocoding:", error);
    }
    return "";
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkAuth = async () => {
      const userId = await getItem("user_id");
      const accessToken = await getItem("access_token");

      if (userId) {
        setIsAuthenticated(true);
      } else {
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
      }
    };

    checkAuth();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated !== null) {
      if (isAuthenticated) {
        router.replace("home"); // Replace with your actual home route
      } else {
        router.replace("/"); // Replace with your actual authentication route
      }
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated, router]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{ isAuthenticated, userLocation, getUserLocation }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);


My (auth)/_layout code :
import React from "react";
import { Redirect, Stack } from "expo-router";
import { useAuth } from "@/context/AuthProvider";

const AuthLayout = () => {
  return (
    <Stack screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="index" />
      <Stack.Screen name="sign-up" />
      <Stack.Screen name="sign-in" />
    </Stack>
  );
};

export default AuthLayout;


My (tabs)/_layout code :
import { Redirect, Tabs } from "expo-router";
import React from "react";

import { TabBarIcon } from "@/components/navigation/TabBarIcon";
import { Colors } from "@/constants/Colors";
import { useColorScheme } from "@/hooks/useColorScheme";
import { icons } from "@/constants";
import { Image, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { useAuth } from "@/context/AuthProvider";

export default function TabLayout() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  // const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();
  // if (isAuthenticated) return <Redirect href="/sign-in" />;

  const TabIcon = ({ icon, color, name, focused }) => {
    return (
      <View className="items-center justify-center gap-2">
        <Image
          source={icon}
          resizeMode="contain"
          tintColor={color}
          className="w-5 h-5"
        />
        <Text
          className={`${focused ? "font-psemibold" : "font-pregular"} text-xs`}
          style={{ color: color }}
        >
          {name}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <Tabs
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
        tabBarActiveTintColor: "#000000",
        tabBarInactiveTintColor: "#8b8b8b",
        tabBarStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "white", // you can't type the name of the css that you have set in the tailwind like the background color for the screen is named primary whose code is #161622  and you want to use the same color for the background of the tab you just can't pass the name because here we are passing the object
          // borderTopColor: 1,
          // borderTopColor: "#232533",
          height: 64,
          elevation: 50,
        },
      }}
    >
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="home"
        options={{
          title: "Home",
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
            <TabIcon
              icon={icons.home}
              color={color}
              name="Home"
              focused={focused}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="track"
        options={{
          title: "Track",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
            <TabIcon
              icon={icons.map}
              color={color}
              name="Track"
              focused={focused}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />

      <Tabs.Screen
        name="setting"
        options={{
          title: "Account Settings",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
            <TabIcon
              icon={icons.settings}
              color={color}
              name="Settings"
              focused={focused}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tabs>
  );
}


Here is my project structure
enter image description here

What do you want? After login when you come to the Home page then if you press the back button app should close, right?

Yes that exactly what i want, but instead it going back to sign in page
